# Script to stop fixed div from scrolling under another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, fixed, sticky

https://rebecca-milazzo-test.squarespace.com/featured#/btr/

I have the page meta-data set to fixed positioning, but as the users scroll, the div doesn't stop and scrolls under the thumbnails at the bottom of the page. I have researched other scripts, but they all are created to stop the div at a certain pixel height and not another element.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: cant you just set the sidebar's `z-index` higher?

Comment: I would like it to stop and not roll over the images if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to create a function that checks the windows scroll position to see whether you've scrolled to the thumbnails section. When you've scrolled to the thumbnails section, set the fixed elements position to absolute and set its top to the windows scroll position plus the original top value. For those like myself who thought z-index would suffice, OP doesn't want the element to go either underneath the thumbnails section or above the thumbnails section on scroll.

```
function checkposition(){
    fixedelement = document.querySelector(".project-meta");
    stopelement = document.querySelector("#project-thumbs");
    stoppoint = stopelement.scrollTop - fixedelement.clientHeight - parseInt(fixedelement.style.top);
    if (window.scrollY >= stoppoint){
        fixedelement.style.position = "absolute";
        fixedelement.style.top = [defaulttophere] + window.scrollY + "px";
    } else {
        fixedelement.style.position = "fixed";
        fixedelement.style.top = [defaulttophere];
    }
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", checkposition);
```

Let me know if this works or not, I threw this together pretty quickly.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping so quickly! I tried both with the additional css (position:fixed) for .project-meta on and off, but it didn't work...